# PHP true or false

Tags: php

I am trying to modify a plugin called the "events calendar" for wordpress, to show past events.

I have found this function:

```
/**
 * Returns true if the query is set for past events, false otherwise
 * 
 * @return bool
 */
function events_displaying_past() {
    global $spEvents;
    return ($spEvents->displaying == "past") ? true : false;
}
```

Iow can I default this to true?

Comment: What do you mean? Under which circumstances the default value should be used?

Comment: I think he means returning true, when this value is not set? In this case `if(!isset($spEvents->displaying)) return true;`

Comment: This question makes no sense. There are two conditions: either `$spEvents->displaying` is `"past"` and the function returns `true`... or the function returns `false`. There is no room for a "default" case.

Comment: `boolean_expr ? true : false` is a bit verbose.. just write `boolean_expr` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/**
     * Returns true if the query is set for past events, false otherwise
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    function events_displaying_past() {
        global $spEvents;
        return ($spEvents->displaying == "past" || !isset($spEvents->displaying)) ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it is better to part this logic to make the code more readable. Also if you take it this way you should at first test isset so it does not try to access an unset value.